# mod_rewrite rewrite url using .htaccess php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new to htaccess rules.

I want a rule that will treat two urls as one.

- http://domain.com/folder/multisite/index.php
- http://domain.com/folder/multisite/sites/client1/index.php

This two should be treated as same URL. I just want to add sites/client1 to URL which actually does nothing. Every URL request should contain sites/client1/.

For next request like

- multisite2/index.php?id_product=1&controller=product
- multisite2/sites/client1/index.php?id_product=1&controller=product

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://domain.com/folder/multisite/sites/client1/index.php should be treated as http://domain.com/folder/multisite/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`RewriteRule index.php?(.*) sites/client1/index.php?$1`

Also please search around a bit before posting here. Some possible duplicates of this question are these:

[.htaccess URL rewrite with one and two query string vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198359/htaccess-url-rewrite-with-one-and-two-query-string-vars)

[htaccess url rewrite to .php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125868/htaccess-url-rewrite-to-php?rq=1)

Comment: hi mtndesign, thanks for the help.
It is now actually redirecting to sites/client1/index.php.
I don't want this i just want to show it in URL. But internally it should stay on http://domain.com/folder/multisite/index.php

Thanks again

Comment: sites/client1/ are just dummy parameters

Comment: You mean you don't want to redirect the user, you just want to treat the `sites/client1/index.php` as `index.php`? Then you should update your question. And as the solution, you should use the `mod_proxy`. Check apache documentation for this and take look at following questions: [q1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206201/why-redirect-keeps-changing-address-bar) [q2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645280/rewrite-url-without-change-address). If you'll need any code, I can provide it to you.

Comment: Oh, I forgot the link to `mod_proxy`. [Here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) it is.

Comment: Have you took a look at the question 1, that I provided to you? That's the code I'm going to post it here.

Comment: i tried that already it's giving me 500 internal server error.
this one 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/client1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/client1/$1 [PL]

Answer (score 1):

This will send all request in /sites/client1/ to /

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sites/client1/(.*)$ $1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: hi silentboy, thanks for the help. Same issue it is now actually redirecting to / . Simply, /sites/client1/ should remain in URL, but internally it should call  domain.com/folder/multisite/index.php

Comment: sites/client1/ are just dummy parameters